# Excel MATCH with Criteria

Tags: excel

I wonder if someone could help me with this issue? 
I have a ranking table and want to MATCH the 5 lowest ratio items (as per below).

```
=MATCH(SMALL(RankMthRat,1),RankMthRat,0)
=MATCH(SMALL(RankMthRat,2),RankMthRat,0)
=MATCH(SMALL(RankMthRat,3),RankMthRat,0)
=MATCH(SMALL(RankMthRat,4),RankMthRat,0)
=MATCH(SMALL(RankMthRat,5),RankMthRat,0)
```

It is possible that the 5 lowest values are all 0%, in which case I would the MATCH position of all 5. 
But because of the 0 value the returned MATCH position for all 5 of the above is the same.

Is it possible to MATCH but ignore previous results? IE the third formula is returns result that is not equal to the first and second?

(RankMthRat is a single column of percentages).

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A standard way of doing this, although you might not consider it to be very elegant, is to add a small amount to each row based on the row number

```
=MATCH(SMALL(INDEX(RankMthRat+ROW(RankMthRat)*0.00001,0),ROW()-ROW($1:$1)),INDEX(RankMthRat+ROW(RankMthRat)*0.00001,0),0)
```

entered in (say) C2.

[image]